# Problema con la muestra de ventanas (pop ups) y actividades

Tags: android, edittext

Estoy teniendo un problema muy grande el cual es que al tocar velozmente y repetidamente un botón que muestre una ventana emergente o una actividad, esta ventana o actividad se abrirá la cantidad de veces que pude tocar el botón antes de que la ventana o actividad se abriera. Me gustaría que esto no pasase y que, en cambio, solo se abriera una ventana o actividad a pesar de la cantidad de veces que se toque el botón.

Comment: inabilita el boton despues de que haces click y volvelo a habilitar cuando termine de abrirse la ventana o despues de que pase un segundo.

Comment: No puedo creer que no se me había ocurrido antes. Muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Puedes usar una variable que determine ya fue activado el botón, puedes deshabilitar el botón, pero en el caso de la Activity puedes usar: android:launchMode="singleTask", @TomasMenniti , saludos.

Comment: No conocía esa propiedad. Aún asi, la acabo de utilizar y no funciona :(

Comment: Por favor no agregues resuelto ni la respuesta a tu pregunta con marcar algun aporte como aceptado o publicar tu solución alcanza

Answer (score 2):

> al tocar velozmente y repetidamente un botón que muestre una ventana
>   emergente o una actividad, esta ventana o actividad se abrirá la
>   cantidad de veces que pude tocar el botón antes de que la ventana o
>   actividad se abriera.

Una opción que funcionaría tanto para una ventana o `Activity` podría realizarse mediante una variable la cual cambiaría su valor a false y no permitiría el proceso nuevamente.

```
private boolean activado;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button button = findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(activado) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(i);

                //Cambia valor
                activado = false;
            }

        }
    });
```

Otra opción para evitar abrir una varias ventanas, se puede realizar deshabilitando el botón.

```
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {

               //Deshabilita el boton.
               v.setEnabled(false);

             }
         });
```

---

**En el caso de una `Activity` si no deseas se abra nuevamente una opción común sería definir la propiedad  `android:launchMode="singleTask"` en tu Activity.**

> android:launchMode="singleTask" permite tener solo una instancia de la
>   Activity en el sistema (a.k.a. Singleton).

```
<activity android:name=".OtherActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

de esta forma aunque realices clic al botón en varias ocasiones, siempre obtendrás solo una instancia de la Activity:

```
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);


             }
         });
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Elena. Pero la propiedad android:launchMode no me funcionó

Comment: Debe ser android:launchMode="singleTask"  en la Activity que no deseas se abra en multiples ocasiones @TomasMenniti

Comment: Exacto, eso mismo hice pero no dió resultados. Igualmente pude resolverlo con un Handler. Gracias igualmente.

Comment: Un poco raro ya que si defines android:launchMode="singleTask" para la Activity esta funciona como un "Singleton".